# Sort a list of cards prolog

Tags: prolog, bubble-sort

I have a list of card structures such as:

```
[card(ace, spades), card(10, diamonds), card(king, clubs)]
```

can anyone help me understand how to sort these according to face value?

I have this:

```
bubblesort(L, L1) :-
        (   bubble(L, L2)
        ->  bubblesort(L2, L1)
        ;   L = L1 ).

bubble([card(A,A2), card(B,B2)|T], L) :-
        (   A > B
        ->  L = [card(B,B2), card(A,A2)|T]
        ;   L = [card(A,A2) | L1],
            bubble([card(B,B2)|T], L1)).
```

which works well (its bubble sort) except when you have `card(ace, spades)` or alike because `ace` is not a number

Comment: Could you explain why you have said that it is wrong??

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? =)

Comment: between ace and king, which one is stronger?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`predsort/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=predsort/3)

It's like `sort/2`, but determines the order of the terms by calling the comparison predicate you fed it. So we only need to write a `compare_values/3` predicate that compares the face values of your cards. My try:

```
compare_values(D, card(A,_), card(B,_)) :-
    nth0(X, [ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, jack, queen, king], A),
    nth0(Y, [ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, jack, queen, king], B),
    compare(D, X, Y).

sort_cards(L, R) :-
    predsort(compare_values, L, R).
```

---

Explanation of the `compare_values/3` predicate:

We need to define an ordering over the following list:

```
[ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, jack, queen, king]
```

how? Given two values `A` and `B`, we simply use `nth0/3` to search for `A` and `B` in the list. `nth0/3` will give us the position of the element we are searching for. So now:

```
X = position of the element A in the ordered list
Y = position of the element B in the ordered list
```

but now `X` and `Y` are guaranteed to be numbers! And we can compare them with the built-in predicate [`compare/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=compare/3). If `X < Y` the card `A` comes before the card `B`, and vice-versa.

`compare/3` will compare `X` and `Y`, and return one of `(>)`, `(<)`, `(=)`.

An example:

```
?- compare_values(D, card(ace, clubs), card(7, spades)).
```

- `nth0` search for `ace` and `7` in the list of ordered values.
- Now `X = 0` and `Y = 6` (the indexes of `ace` and `7` in the list)
- `compare(D, 0, 6)` unifies with `D = (<)`

Finally: the `predsort/3` predicate uses compare_values to sort the list accordingly to the order defined `by compare_values/3`

---

A query:

```
?- sort_cards([card(king, spades), card(ace,spades), card(3, clubs), card(7,diamonds), card(jack,clubs)], X). 

X = [card(ace, spades), card(3, clubs), card(7, diamonds), card(jack, clubs), card(king, spades)].
```

Comment: +1 for the exclamation mark. :) but between ace and king, which one ranks higher?

Comment: @Lilz, well, just put it at the end of the list. I just gave an example, you can define whatever ordering you prefer.